# Had people related the work of Gogol before "The Nose"?

Tags: short-stories, russian-language, nikolai-gogol

In *The Nose*, an opera by Demitri Shostakovich, Shostakovich combines many of Nikolai Gogol's stories, including *The Nose*, for which the opera is named, into a single story. Had previous critics or writers analyzed the works of Nikolai Gogol as a single story?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand your question. Do you mean reviews from critics or author ? If so, the answer is yes. Gogol was a good friend of Pushkin, who promoted his short stories and encouraged him to write  *The Dead Souls*. Also, Gogol was the protégé of the most influential Russian critic of the 1840’s, Vissarion Belinsky, at least until the publication of *The Dead Souls*. Gogol was also a major influence for Dostoyevsky, Sologub, Belyi, and more generally for the Silver Age of Russian Literature (1890’s-1920’s).
I don’t if I answered your question.

Comment: Hi, the question is whether critics or authors had ever treated Gogol's oeuvre as is it were a single work, instead of a series of works. I would also like to point out that answers should not be used for requests for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, I’m new here and I couldn’t find the button to add a comment on the question. Concerning your question, you can read In the Shadow of Gogol of Abram Terts/Andrei Sinyavski, Merezhkovsky’s Gogol and the Devil, or Gogol from Dmitri Ovsyaniko-Kulikovsky